# How to filter redundant features using shap.utils.hclust not only by visual inspection barplot?

Tags: python, machine-learning, feature-selection, hierarchical-clustering, shap

I'm using `shap.utils.hclust` to figure out which features are redundant and following the [documentation](https://shap-lrjball.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/plots/bar.html)

Reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import shap

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

from lightgbm import LGBMClassifier

data = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gdmarmerola/random-stuff/master/probability_calibration/UCI_Credit_Card.csv")

# getting design matrix and target
X = data.copy().drop(['ID','default.payment.next.month'], axis=1)
y = data.copy()['default.payment.next.month']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = .2, random_state = 42)

model = LGBMClassifier(random_state = 42).fit(X_train, y_train)

# compute SHAP values
explainer = shap.Explainer(model, X_test)
shap_values = explainer(X_test)

clustering = shap.utils.hclust(X_test, y_test) # by default this trains (X.shape[1] choose 2) 2-feature XGBoost models
shap.plots.bar(shap_values, clustering=clustering)
```

It retrieves the following plot:

[image]

My questions are:

1. In the implementation why is [this](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/46b3800b31df04745416da27c71b216f91d61775/shap/utils/_clustering.py#L110) an `XGBRegressor` even for classification tasks?
2. How can I use `clustering`to remove redundant features, beyond the bar plot visual inspection?

**UPDATE:**

My main question is:

In this toy example, how can I use the `(22,4)` shape output matrix to check which features are in the same cluster and thus being able to reduce the dimensionality? I have a data frame with more than 10,000 features, that's why visual inspection is not feasible.

```
array([[15.        , 16.        ,  0.2877219 ,  2.        ],
       [12.        , 13.        ,  0.36595157,  2.        ],
       [11.        , 24.        ,  0.37372008,  3.        ],
       [14.        , 25.        ,  0.420607  ,  4.        ],
       [23.        , 26.        ,  0.43781072,  6.        ],
       [ 9.        , 10.        ,  0.45111704,  2.        ],
       [21.        , 27.        ,  0.50203449,  7.        ],
       [20.        , 29.        ,  0.51782125,  8.        ],
       [18.        , 30.        ,  0.52462131,  9.        ],
       [17.        , 31.        ,  0.52700263, 10.        ],
       [ 8.        , 28.        ,  0.52802497,  3.        ],
       [19.        , 32.        ,  0.54064447, 11.        ],
       [ 5.        ,  6.        ,  0.56145751,  2.        ],
       [ 7.        , 33.        ,  0.57828146,  4.        ],
       [35.        , 36.        ,  0.62561315,  6.        ],
       [34.        , 37.        ,  0.66345358, 17.        ],
       [22.        , 38.        ,  0.6892271 , 18.        ],
       [ 0.        , 39.        ,  0.76330948, 19.        ],
       [ 4.        , 40.        ,  0.91275334, 20.        ],
       [ 2.        , 41.        ,  0.94387454, 21.        ],
       [ 1.        , 42.        ,  0.98299891, 22.        ],
       [ 3.        , 43.        ,  0.98913395, 23.        ]])
```

Comment: Please consider this [ask] and consequently asking 1 question at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Underneath, even tree models for classification are regression tasks. SHAP calls it "raw" feature output space, Tensorflow would call it logits. To convert raw to proba space sigmoid or softmax are used. So, answering your first question:

> ```
> Distances are measured by training univariate XGBoost models 
> of y for all the features, and then predicting the output of these
> models using univariate XGBoost models of other features. If one 
> feature can effectively predict the output of another feature's 
> univariate XGBoost model of y, then the second feature is 
> redundant with the first with respect to y. A distance of 1 corresponds 
> to no redundancy while a distance of 0 corresponds to perfect 
> redundancy (measured using the proportion of variance explained). 
> Note these distances are not symmetric.
> ```

In plain English, they add features 1 by 1 and see if the added feature adds predictive power in raw space, measured by R2. If yes, they say distance is big (different cluster). If not, they say distance is small (same cluster).

2. The only info you can infer from the clustering is that features are pretty close from the model's predictive ability perspective, given the sample. As a rule, omitting additional feature will be lossy unless it's (i) a white noise, (ii) has structure but uncorrelated in broad sense with the output, or (iii) model memorizes data. Different model may have a different opinion if it's in the same "cluster" or not.

In general, I would use SHAP for model or data explanation ("true to model" or "true to data"), and experiment planning. I wouldn't expect it help me with feature selection while tuning models with already collected data. But it may depend on your particular objective, e.g. output most parsimonious model or adjust your data if you suspect overfitting.

**UPDATE**

```
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy
hierarchy.dendrogram(clustering, labels=X_train.columns);
```

[image]

```
hierarchy.cut_tree(clustering, n_clusters=5)
```

or

```
hierarchy.cut_tree(clustering, height=.5)
```

Output is cluster labels. Choose "any".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why I would not use SHAP for feature selection? I'm trying to find redundant features from the clustering matrix by first knowing what features are close to each other and then deciding what features I want to remove based on that.

Comment: What is the definition of a redundant feature and how it's related to clustering?

Comment: redundant means that a model could use either feature and still get the same accuracy

Comment: If you're interested in answering a question like this, why not brute forcibly eliminate all features till 0, while tuning your models to the best hyperparms, and see what's best? And still having in mind that you're dealing with a sample? On top of that, why do you believe that pretty basic clustering will apply to your optimally tuned model?

Comment: See update. Risks are yours.

Comment: @Multivac If this answers your question (and I believe it does) you may kindly think about  accepting.

Comment: It guided me in the right direction, thank you and no need to ask for choosing it as the best answer; it merits itself :)

Comment: Side note. If you have many features you dont need to find 'redundant' ones, unless youre after a parsimonious explainable model. Trees are oretty accommodative of such situations, given enough regularization. Anyways, if given such a task, i would start old school filtering out correlated and constant featuresm no need to do fancy boosted trees.